# How do I use the --header option to send cookies with Siege?

Tags: cookies, webserver, load-testing, stress-testing

I have just started to use Siege to do load/stressing test on a new web server. I am trying to test on my most resource/performance heavy script, but the script requires cookies. What is the proper format for using the --header option in siege?

I have tried this with no luck:

siege --header="Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=--COOKIE--; iptoken=--COOKIE--" http://www.myurl.com/script.php,

There is no documentation on this that I could find, so any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is to use `--header="Cookie: --COOKIE_DATA--"` (ref. [wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Siege](http://wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Siege)).

Comment: Example from the site: `siege --concurrent=1 --reps=5 --header="Cookie: rbkSignon=XXXXX" http://vmbuild.apache.org/continuum/groupSummary.action`.

Comment: Thanks for this! FYI The link is now dead :(