# How do I get siege to use the cookies for benchmark and load testing

Tags: session-cookies, performance-testing

I've setup siege (v2.70) to test a webapp that has a login, and then I have a list of about 180 urls to stress test the speed of the app.  Problem is that the cookie is being ignored when returned by the login url.

Here is a tcpdump of the network traffic between siege and the app (box.example.org has been substituted for the actual url, that is not the problem)

You can see the Set-Cookie in the first response, and then fail to see the cookie in in the next GET request.  I found this:

[How do I use the --header option to send cookies with Siege?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242914/how-do-i-use-the-header-option-to-send-cookies-with-siege)

but the cookie I need to send is dependent on the login, I can't just hard code it.  The [FAQ](http://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/h/siege-faq#a18) says it supports them, but tcpdump argues otherwise:

```
20:25:48.003094 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31699, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 223)
    192.168.20.34.48923 > 192.168.20.81.80: Flags [P.], seq 2734994720:2734994891, ack 3331849910, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 2229194446 ecr 50245070], length 171
E...{.@.@......"...Q...P... ...............
........GET /saml/testlogon/ HTTP/1.1^M
Host: box.example.org^M
Accept: */*^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip^M
User-Agent: JoeDog/1.00 [en] (X11; I; Siege 2.70)^M
Connection: close^M
^M

20:25:48.406571 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21369, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 427)
    192.168.20.81.80 > 192.168.20.34.48923: Flags [P.], seq 1:376, ack 171, win 972, options [nop,nop,TS val 50245160 ecr 2229194446], length 375
E...Sy@.@.<....Q...".P...............*.....
...(....HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND^M
Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2012 02:33:32 GMT^M
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)^M
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding^M
Set-Cookie: sessionid=233511e6001797ec77f7f3a08683ce97; httponly; Path=/^M
Location: http://box.example.org/viewer/start/^M
Content-Encoding: gzip^M
Content-Length: 20^M
Connection: close^M
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8^M
^M
....................
20:25:49.410684 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3041, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 221)
    192.168.20.34.48924 > 192.168.20.81.80: Flags [P.], seq 1168563186:1168563355, ack 1414846755, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 2229194798 ecr 50245422], length 169
E.....@.@..v..."...Q...PE...TT.#...........
........GET /viewer/start/ HTTP/1.1^M
Host: box.example.org^M
Accept: */*^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip^M
User-Agent: JoeDog/1.00 [en] (X11; I; Siege 2.70)^M
Connection: close^M
^M

20:25:49.419109 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30222, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 375)
    192.168.20.81.80 > 192.168.20.34.48924: Flags [P.], seq 1:324, ack 169, win 972, options [nop,nop,TS val 50245424 ecr 2229194798], length 323
E..wv.@.@......Q...".P..TT.#E........*.....
...0....HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND^M
Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2012 02:33:34 GMT^M
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)^M
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding^M
Location: http://box.example.org/saml/testlogon/?next=/viewer/start/^M
Content-Encoding: gzip^M
Content-Length: 20^M
Connection: close^M
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8^M
^M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in siege itself.  I fixed the code and pushed it to this repo

https://github.com/mark0978/siege

siege did not expect the httponly; (has no =) and if the expires time is not present, it got the expiration wrong too.  The last one I could have fixed by setting an expiration time in my app, but instead I just fixed the calculation.

Comment: Why are URLS not underlined on SO?  And why are they so close to the same color as the regular text?